# How could a function registered in an effect hook run though an empty array dependency is passed to the effect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a registered `onmousemove` event in useEffect as follows. But in order not to run the effect every time the component renders I pass it an empty array dependency. But still the function that handles the event is called. But the function is inside useEffect. How could this be possible?

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const UseEffect1 = () => {
  const [X, setX] = useState(0);
  const [Y, setY] = useState(0);

  const handleMouseMove = (e) => {
    setX(e.clientX);
    setY(e.clientY);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("onmousemove", handleMouseMove);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        width {X} - height {Y}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UseEffect1;
```

Comment: Once you register the event listener (which you do in the useEffect hook), it stays active until you [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)

Answer (score 0):

The `useEffect` hook is called every time the component renders.

As you have registered  `onmousemove` inside `useEffect`, the `handleMouseMove` function is called after rendering of component.